# Group of symmetries of circle contains elements of all orders

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be the symmetry group of a circle.

I tried to answer the following question:

Show that $G$ contains elements of every finite order as well as elements of infinite order.

My answer:

Let $n \in \mathbb N_{>0}$. Then the rotation by $360/n$ has order $n$ hence we can find an element of order $n$ for any $n >0$.

Now we need to show that there exist elements of infinite order. To this end, let $R$ be rotation by $360/\sqrt{2}$. Then $R$ has infinite order because  $n \sqrt{2} \neq 360 k$ for all $n,k \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$.

To see this, note that if  $n \sqrt{2} =360 k$ for some $n,k \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$ then

$$ 2n^2 = 360^2 k^2$$

which is equivalent to

$$ \left({n \over k}\right)^2 = {360^2 \over 2}$$

${360^2 \over 2}$ is an integer which implies $k=1$. So we have

$$ n^2 = {360^2 \over 2} = 64800$$

Now note that $254^2=64516$ < 64800 < 255^2=65025$$

This concludes the proof.

> Is my answer correct?

-

> And if it is, is there a better way than trial and error to find
>   numbers such that $64800$ is between their squares to finish the proof?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. (Though you should get into the habit of using radians instead of degrees)

Comment: The proof is fine. Minor typo, but I know what you mean. We want $n\ne 0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas No, I don't understand what the typo is: in the first instance I want $n$ to be positive just because it makes no difference whether we consider negative rotations or positive ones. In the second instance I guess I should have written $\mathbb Z^\times$. So I guess not just $n$ but also $k$ must be non zero. Is that the typo you are referring to?

Comment: Yes,  $n$ was chosen positive earlier, so everything is OK. But then towards the end comes the technically wrong assertion that $n\sqrt{2}\ne 360k$ for all $n,k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I edited the question. Did I improve it?

Comment: I don't think the "To see this" part is necessary. The fact that there are no positive integers $n$ and $k$ such that $n\sqrt{2}=360k$ is immediately equivalent to the fact $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, and I would assume you are far along enough that the fact can be taken for granted, you have seen enough proofs of it. There is actually a gap in your proof, "which implies $k=1$ is not true unless $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime, and even for that it requires proof.  You would not prove irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ by saying that $(p/q)^2=2$ which implies $k=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you very much for your comment. I will try to fix the issue with the gap. OTOH, although I know that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational I don't see how $n\sqrt{2} = 360 k$ is an immediate consequence.

Comment: Suppose to the contrary that there exist positive integers $n$ and $k$ such that $n\sqrt{2}=360k$. Then $\sqrt{2}=\frac{360k}{n}$, so $\sqrt{2}$ is rational. It really is immediate! Writing another proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, with the irrelevant $360$ thrown in, really is a waste of time.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ooops, right, I did not see that. That's much better! Thank you!

Comment: @AndréNicolas Another thank you to you because this also resolves my other question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1518287/180995).

Comment: You are welcome. The first part of the first comment  I made is the relevant one. The proof is fine, clearly expressed.

Comment: Had he used $2\pi$ instead of 360 this proof would not have worked as it stands correct? How can this proof be edited to use $2\pi$ instead.

Comment: What is symmetry group of circle? Can you give some reference.?